# Count word occurrences in a new column in R

Tags: r, loops, count, agrep

How should I use 'agrep' function in a loop to count the 'number of mentions' in the reviews about attraction_name?

Dataset_1 has 10k reviews and Dataset_2 has 90 attraction_names.

Dataset_1$review_text <- c("I like park_1 compared to park_2", "Park_3 is highly recommended")

Dataset_2$attraction_name <- c("park_1","park_2","park_3")

Ideally, I want to have a column in Dataset_1 which shows how many times attractions are mentioned in total for each review. For example, in the case above, the first review will have a count of 2.

Thanks in advance for your reply.

For now, I have something like below.

`# Go through every review and see how many approximate matches
there are for each review

#Create empty list for the results of loop.

```
rides <- ride_data$name
```

#This loop counts the approximate matches

```
for (i in 1:length(rides)) {

  dataset <- disney_data$Review_Text

  ride_to_search <- rides[i]

  result[[i]] <- length(test <-agrep(ride_to_search,dataset,value=T))
  i = i+1
}`
```

Comment: `agrep` is for fuzzy text-matching - you will need to decide in a minimal distance (i.e. number of characters to change to count as a match) and include it in your question. Or are you just interested in exact matches?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your instant reply. I assume I want to see how many approximate matches there are for each park because some reviewers may not spell the full name for those parks.

Comment: OK - it doesn't work that well with the example you gave because `agrep("park 1", "park 2")` will be a match as they're one character off. Assuming that your real names are not, however, you'll probably want to do something like `col1 = agrep(pattern1, review_text)`, and so on for each pattern.

Comment: Sorry for my unclear example. The attraction names vary quite a lot. Thank you for your hint. I am still wondering how should I get the total number of mentions for each review in dataset 1. Any suggestions?